# How can I refresh resolv.conf after changing the resolv options in the interfaces file?

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolv.conf

After bringing up a dhcp controlled instance in AWS I have made changes to the /etc/network/interfaces file for custom nameserver and DNS search strings:

```
auto lo
auto eth0
iface lo inet loopback
dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1 9.9.9.9
dns-search flapjacks.io flapjacks.net

iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I was hoping to be able to restart a service to get resolv.conf to reflect these changes, but I do not know the service to restart... the changes do show up after reboot however. Does anyone know what service should update this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

The `-v` for verbose should produce sufficient outptut to see that the process completed successfully.

Comment: Didn't work. Looks to have restarted DHCP + ifup and ifdown but the resolv.conf has not been updated.

Comment: Does resolv.conf contain 127.0.0.xx suggesting that dnsmasq is running? What does this report? `sudo systemd-resolve --status` It should show the DNS naeservers to be used in absence of a cached lookup previously supplied by dnsmasq. I doubt that you really want to bypass or disable dnsmasq.

Comment: dnsmasq is not installed / running - and your command does not appear valid: "systemd-resolve: unrecognized option '--status'"

Comment: I'm not sure what all you did to remove dnsmasq. Is systed running? `ps aux | grep systemd` Which version are you running? `lsb-release -d` and also: `uname -r`

Comment: This is 16.04 LTS server - 4.4.0-131-generic - why would i need dnsmasq?

Comment: You would only want to use dnsmasq because it is generally faster and because it works even when an external DNS nameserver is down.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following commands:

```
sudo resolvconf --enable-updates
sudo resolvconf -u
sudo systemctl restart resolvconf.service
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

To see which DNS servers currently in use (for Ubuntu 22.04+):

```
resolvectl status
```